# cambiar de orientación una gráfica DCA

Tags: r

Me gustaría saber como poder hacer rotar la imagen del DCA en el script de R

[image: DCA a modificar]

Para que este DCA quedara en la misma orientación que este otro DCA

[image: DCA con la orientación correcta]

Para hacer ambos DCA he seguido el mismo script pero diferentes bases de datos:

## Load packages.

```
      library(readr)
      library(vegan)
      library(reshape2)
```

## Load Raw data.

```
      colnames(ngs.data)[c(1)] <- c("habitat") ; head(ngs.data); dim(ngs.data)

      ngs.data.coll.dca <- acast(ngs.data, collection+habitat ~ taxon , fill = 0); head(ngs.data.coll.dca); dim(ngs.data.coll.dca)

      rownames(ngs.data.coll.dca)
```

## Create plot parameters from rowname attributes.

```
      raw.site.hab <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(ngs.data.coll.dca), "_"), "[[", 2); head(raw.site.hab)


      site.des <- c("Wl1F", "Wl2F", "Wl4F", "Wl4P", "Ed1F", "Ed1P", "Ed1V", "Ed2F", "Ed2P",
          "Ed2V", "Ed3F", "Ed3P", "Ed3V", "Ed4F", "Ed4P", "M1V", "M2V", 
          "M3V", "M4V", "M5V", "M7V", "M8V", "Oa1F", "Oa1P", "Oa2F", "Oa2P", 
          "Oa3F", "Oa4F", "Oa4P", "Z1V", "Z2V")
      length(site.des)
```

## Perform DCA

```
      coll.dca <- decorana(ngs.data.coll.dca)
```

## Variance contribtutions of axes.

```
      coll.dca$evals/sum(coll.dca$evals)

      plot(coll.dca, 
 type = "n",
 cex.main = 0.75,
 cex.lab = .75,
 axes = TRUE, 
 cex.axis = 0.5,
 yaxt = "n",
 xlim = c(-8, 18), 
 ylim = c(-4, 10),
 #main = "Raw data", 
 xlab = "DCA1 (0.334 total variance)", 
 ylab = "DCA2 (0.229 total variance)")

      axis(2, at=c(-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10), tick = TRUE, cex.axis = 0.5)

      points(coll.dca, col = as.integer(as.factor(raw.site.hab)), 
   pch = as.integer(as.factor(raw.site.hab)))
```

toda sugerencia es bien recibida, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te entiendo bien quisieras que las cruces verdes aparezcan a la izquierda en el primer gráfico. Para eso bastaría invertir las coordenadas de x. Puedes usar `xlim = rev(range(x))` como en ejemplo:

```
x <- seq(-4, 4, length = 10)
y <- exp(x) / (1 + exp(x))
plot(x,y, xlim = rev(range(x)))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No puede replicar tu gráfica por falta de datos, pero espero que esto pueda ayudarte. En tu caso deberías usar `xlim = rev(range(c(-8, 18)))`, en el gráfico que deseas invertir.

Comment: he probado la función rev aquí, pero no me da ningún resultado plot(rev(coll.dca),  type = "n", cex.main = 0.75, cex.lab = .75,
 axes = TRUE,  cex.axis = 0.5, yaxt = "n", xlim = c(-8, 18), 
 ylim = c(-4, 10),  xlab = "DCA1 (0.334 total variance)", 
 ylab = "DCA2 (0.229 total variance)")

Comment: Debes usarla donde defines el limite de x así : `xlim = rev(c(-8, 18))`. Tu función quedaría como:`plot(coll.dca, type = "n", cex.main = 0.75, cex.lab = .75, axes = TRUE, cex.axis = 0.5, yaxt = "n", xlim = rev(c(-8, 18)), ylim = c(-4, 10), xlab = "DCA1 (0.334 total variance)", ylab = "DCA2 (0.229 total variance)")`

Comment: ¡¡eso era!! muchas gracias